# Why won't this function return whether the username has already been taken?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My aim is to make sure that duplicate usernames cannot exist, so during registration if a user attempts to sign up with a username that another user owns, an error message will appear. I'm a beginner coder, and have had some difficulty digesting the Firebase documentation. In addition, I can't seem to find a direct answer that works for me online.

My code is:

```
func checkIfUsernameExists() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let usernameSearch = db.collection("users")
    let username = usernameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let query = usernameSearch.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("username is free")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                print("username is taken")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

It does successfully print "username is taken", when I attempt to sign up with a username I know already exists. But, it does not tell me when the "username is free".

I am using Cloud Firestore, and I have a collection "users", which contains the fields "email", "firstname", "lastname", "uid" and "username" stored under separate, auto-generated ID documents.

Any help would be massively appreciated, and I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no results is not an error, so it never goes into your `if let error = error {` block. You'll want to explicitly check if the `snapshot` has any results:

```
let query = usernameSearch.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("error: "+error)
    } else {
        if snapshot!.isEmpty {
            print("username is free")
        }
        else {
            print("username is taken")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Words cannot begin to describe my gratitude. Thank you!